# Google Chrome Mic Issue OpenVBX

Tags: flash, google-chrome, microphone

I am using the OpenVBX phone software by Twilio and everytime a call
comes into the software and I click answer it pops up the flash dialog
box but nothing is there. It works perfect in firefox, I just prefer
to use google chrome

**here is my screenshots:** [image: http://morxmedia.com/ss/1.png]**(call coming in)** [image: http://morxmedia.com/ss/2.png]**(after clicking 'answer')** [image: http://morxmedia.com/ss/3.png]**(after closing the flash dialog)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have flash installed do this:

Go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html

Click the first tab (privacy) that shows a globe and an eye in the computer display. Make sure that you set to "always ask".

It is also possible that you set it to deny the first time it asked you. In this case, make sure you clear out all settings in flash and try again. If you selected deny and had remember settings checked, it won't ask you again.

Comment: I tried this. I still am promoted with a message less box. As seen here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RQJUb.png

Comment: Can you plz post a screenshot of what happens when you go here? http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing a SSL certificate and running OpenVBX via HTTPS. It seems like Chrome doesn't allow access to the microphone for unsecured sites, but it works fine when the site is served via HTTPS.

*note* If like me your first inclination is to use a self-signed SSL certificate, don't. Twilio doesn't seem to work with self-signed SSL certificates. I was able to use letsencrypt (which appears to be a free SSL certificate service) and that worked fine and was accepted by Twilio. Additionally, there's a nice command line tool that allows you to get the SSL installed and configured for your web server with just a few console commands. Highly recommended.